# Use ng-repeat with Include Template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple JSON data to iterate in `ng-repeat` but I am having a problem. When I iterate through the data, angular repeats the data without HTML of the repeat's div but I just want the inner HTML.

For example:

**Data**

```
 ...

 $scope.tests = [{text:'text1'},{text:'text2'},{text:'text3'}];

 ...
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="out-div" ng-repeat="test in tests">
  <p>{{test.text}}</p> <b>bold text</b>
</div>
```

The expected response should be like this:

```
<p>text1</p> <b>bold text</b>
<p>text2</p> <b>bold text</b>
<p>text3</p> <b>bold text</b>
```

I just want the inner HTML, is it possible?

Comment: I think you should take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: What do you mean by the inner HTML? What exactly do you want to see as a result and what result are you getting right now? I think the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put ng-repeat in `<p>` instead of parent `<div>` like below:

```
<div id="out-div">
    <p ng-repeat-start="test in tests">{{test.text}}</p>
    <b ng-repeat-end>bold text</b>
</div>
```

This will repeat only `<p>` and `<b>` tags and not parent `<div>`.

Comment: it just give me one b element.

Comment: I don't think so. I've used it this way with expected results. Check the [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: Then you can select it as an answer and help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to refer to the **test** property of the test iterable in your ng-repeat instead of **text** like this:

```
<div id="out-div" ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <p>{{test.test}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I could not express my self, p element just an example, there could be another elements with p, I am editing my question agian.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this, If you just want p tag to repeat:

```
<div id="out-div">
  <div ng-repeat="t in tests">
  <p>{{t.text}}</p>
  <b>bold text</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obXREK

Comment: sorry, this is not what I want. I think I could not express my self, so I edited my question again.

Comment: thanks again, but there is same problem, I dont want out html of ng-repeat's div, I just want to inner html.

Comment: Yes, you can not repeat two tag at a same moment, you need to wrap this tag inside any HTML Tag

Comment: Ohw :( its not usefull thanks, I resource for alternative ways

Answer (score 0):

`ngRepeat` repeats everything from current div and "inside" to the inner HTML. You cannot change that behavior, though you can create your own directive and implement whatever you want.

Knowing that, you can build your template to address it with proper `id` and `class` tags appropriately.

```
<div id="out-div">
    <p ng-repeat="test in tests">
        {{test.test}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="test in tests">
          &lt;p&gt;{{test.test}}&lt;/p&gt;
      </div>
</body>
```

[plunker code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/25ms2w2BEk2iZXKJTis5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can use span to acheive this

```
<span ng-repeat="test in tests">
<p >{{test.test}}</p> <b>bold text</b>
</span>
```

it wont affect your styling

Comment: I just want out put, span will be my output hmtl again.